# Updating existing MySQL record with Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

Java/Spring/MySQL Application.
Trying to UPDATE a MySQL 'int(11)' type field.

POJO is defined as:
@Entity/@Component: @Column(name="time")
private int time;

```
         public int updtTm(@Param("id") int id, @Param("time") int time)  {
         javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE GAME_DATA SET TIME=:time WHERE ID=:id");
         int updateCount = query.setParameter("id", id)
                                .setParameter("time", time)
                                .executeUpdate();
         return updateCount;
```

Both params passed in are verified as 'int'.  This is the exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [44] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:897) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]

Why does Java think the expected type is a 'Date'?

Comment: So you've got a MySql column called "TIME" of type `int` - how does that work?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. It might be a poor name for a column/field...but it's a javascript counter in seconds on a web page that is simply stored as an int.

Comment: Can you show the output of `show create table GAME_DATA`?

Comment: Not much 'output' from my hosting:

 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0339 seconds.)
CREATE TABLE `GAME_DATA` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, `user_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, `datetime` datetime NOT NULL, `game` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `time` int(11) NOT NULL, `code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Hmm. See if you get on any better by surrounding `TIME` (col name) with backticks

Comment: Good thought.... it did have ticks when I copy/pasted it here. This editor must have removed them when I submitted it. I might try to make everything string for that field just to try to get more data.

Comment: Even making the TIME DB Field a VARCHAR, as well as making the Java objects/methods VARCHAR, I get the same exception:

Parameter value [35] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]

Comment: When I hard code the:

UPDATE GAME_DATA SET TIME=22 WHERE ID=:id

It works OK.

Comment: We don't actually know for certain whether that *is* the column in question. You have another column with arguably an even 'worse' name, i.e. "datetime". Backtick that one as well. In fact, to remove all doubt, backtick them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be with the field named, `time` since it is a reserved word.

Try renaming the field to something else and try.

```
SET TIME=:new_field_name
```

might work.

Comment: After renaming the DB field from 'TIME' to 'TIMER', and updating the JAVA references, it's working.  Thank you @g00se and hermit